# enum polymorphism implementation

Tags: kotlin

Consider an interface:

```
interface class  IPage {

}
```

and two enums implementing this interface as

```
enum class Page1 : IPage{ ..... }
enum class Page2 : IPage{ ..... }
```

Now I have a method

```
fun getPage(isSomeCondition : Boolean) : IPage{
    if(isSomeCondition) return Page1 
    else return Page2
}
```

However I am getting a compile time error:

Classifier Page1 does not have a companion object and must be initialized here, I believe that is happening because of the interface, but I am out of ideas on how to solve it!

More explanation:

Both of these enums hold values which are similar, basis the boolean condition I want to load either of the enums and work on the values contained inside of that enum.

consider for example my enums with an updated signature:

```
enum Page1(val title: String, val data : Data)
```

Now my Data class has various implementations like ChildData | ParentData | FriendData etc

example:

```
 enum Page1(val title: String, val data : Data){
    PARENT("Heiachi", ParentData(...)),
    CHILD("JIN", ChildData(...))

 }


enum Page2(val title: String, val data : Data){
        PARENT("Hworang", FriendData(...)),
        CHILD("Yoshimitsu", FoeData(....))

}
```

Where

```
class ParentData : Data 
class ChildData : Data
class FriendData : Data
class FoeData : Data
```

Comment: Shouldn't `return Page1` be `return Page1.one-of-the-enum-values`?

Comment: is `IPage` enum class or an `interface`? something is wrong

Comment: Ah my bad, IPage is an interface, that was a typo in the question! Changed it now.

Comment: also, why are Page1 and Page2 are enum classes, they should have some enum values defined in it. The return value from getPage should be an enum value. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that is the actual issue - both enums hold different values of same type, I want to fetch either based on the boolean condition in getPage and use that particular enum at runtime. Maybe there is a better way to implement such a scenario apart from enums

Comment: if Page1 has enum values P11 and P12, which value do you want to return from the method?

Comment: I have updated the question, the data inside the enum is different - again polymorphic

Comment: how about returning actual enum values? `if(condition) return Page1.PARENT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to iterate the children of the enum that you've been returning? If so, you can return the implementations of the enums, not the enum definitions:

```
fun getPage(isSomeCondition : Boolean) : Iterable<IPage>{
    if(isSomeCondition) return Page1.values()
    else return Page2.values()
}
```

Alternatively, you can make a class that defines a parent or child. You can then optionally store thes in a single enum or just make them conform to another interface.

```
class PageType(val title: String, val data : Data)

enum Page(val parent: PageType, val child: PageType) {
    Page1(PageType("Heiachi", ParentData(...)), PageType(("JIN", ChildData(...))),
    Page2(PageType("Hworang", FriendData(...)), PageType("Yoshimitsu", FoeData(....))
}

fun getPage(isSomeCondition : Boolean) : Page {
    if(isSomeCondition) return Page.Page1 
    else return Page.Page2
}

// Alternative to enum:

interface Page {
    val parent: PageType
    val child: PageType
}
object Page1: Page {
    override val parent = PageType("Heiachi", ParentData(...))
    override val child = PageType(("JIN", ChildData(...))
}
object Page2: Page {
    override val parent = PageType("Hworang", FriendData(...))
    override val child = PageType(("Hworang", FoeData(...))
}
```